# ASync log method

Tags: c#, silverlight, async-await

I want to create a custom logger, which can be used in Silverlight client and within a WCF service.

We use the ASync framework in VS2012RC.

I am struggling with creating a method that is mainly **a void**, but must return a Task.

```
public Task Log(string message, LogCategory logCategory, LogType logType)
{

}
```

Within this void, the logging code will be excuted.

Comment: @Patrick Peters: This question(?) is kind of a VOID :D

Comment: public async Task LogASync(string message, LogCategory logCategory, LogType logType) works now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public async Task LogASync(string message, LogCategory logCategory, LogType logType)
```

works